# Understanding why cannot be used "async" in the <script> tag of Adword Remarketing Tag

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-ads-api

I am working to improve my pageload speed to reduce block rendering of the page I am inserting various .js files with the `async` tag or `defer`.

Unfortunatly I read in the documentation of "AdWords Remarketing Tag" the following

> Please don't modify the script tag to use the async parameter as it
>   can lead to unpredictable behaviour.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/

Therefore I am not really clear what would be the trade off of not inserting

```
<script async src="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"></script>
```

vs the suggested

```
<script src="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"></script>
```

If I add the `async` tag, I can clearly see in the google developer that the Network priority change from "high" to "low". But what would be this "unpredictable behaviour"? what actually would happen?

Answer (score 0):

If the scripts are meant to be loaded synchronously, then you should stick to that.  The consequences of loading them out of order will likely be undefined variables/objects or unmet dependencies.  If you try to access a variable before it is set by the other script, you will run into a show-stopping exception of some kind.  You may not run into this in your implementation, but rest assured that is merely luck and this type of error might occur on throttled or slower connections.

Comment: The script is composed by two section, one is the definition of parameters that I leave synchronous direclty in the HTML, and the second the "conversion.js" that is invoking those info that I want to async. The only thing that I think that could couse problem calling it later, is if someone close the page earlier than the script is loaded (which for me is acceptable drawback). The reason that I aboslutely want to make it async, is because any script loaded sync. it will stop paint rendering of html making it apparently slower to the user (I am still running on HTTP 1.1).

Comment: But I wonder if there are more drawbacks reason other than that. I am not an expert of networking and I do not understand what actually conversion.js is actually doing (couldn't find any material online explaining line by line). And obviously, I don't just accept description that doesn't explain why something is negative without clarifying the why, because I prefer to decide on what drawbacks I prefer to have in my code based on situations.

Comment: The throttle wouldn't be a problem because parametres are always loaded first. And I am ok with the script loading way after the html page is loaded. I think that analytics shouldn't interfer with the speed of loading of essential elements and interaction behaviour of the page. They can be loaded after or even lose them (for example very slow connection that create problem).

Answer (score 0):

The script makes use of [`Document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) to insert some elements into the page.

From the documentation of `Document.write`:

> Note: document.write in deferred or asynchronous scripts will be
>   ignored, and you'll get a message like "A call to document.write()
>   from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored" in the
>   error console.

In the [minified script](https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js), you can find two occurrences of `d.write` at positions 32:181 and 32:382.